# What is the difference between "next to, beside, by, and near"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I'm wondering if there is any difference between these prepositions especially in expressing position
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "next to" and "beside" are identical to me in meaning, signifying immediate adjacency. "near" is a little more approximate and to me, implies it isn't "next to" but just "fairly close". This works for any scale from buildings to cutlery.

"by" is a little more vague. I think on its own, it means the same as "beside"; "walking by the river" means the same to me as "beside".

example: *my* spoon is next to *my* plate, but the sugar bowl is only "near" (its on the table, so fairly close, but not probably not next to my plate)